# Is it possible to use two polarised filters to create a variable ND filter?

Tags: filters, polarizer, neutral-density

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between using an ND filter versus 2 polarizers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12645/what-is-the-difference-between-using-an-nd-filter-versus-2-polarizers)

I was reading that by attaching two polarised filter we could create a variable ND filter.

Has anyone done this? How was this done? Any drawback (colour cast, quality...)? What would be the strength in light filtering of such filter?